# How to save selected view highlighted in rcp application?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have an Eclipse RCP application. In a perspective there are four views and I want to highlight respective views whenever I click on them. Is it possible to do it?
i have tried following code:

```
private void addFocusBackgroundOnSelectingView() {
    viewer.getControl().addListener(SWT.MouseEnter, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            viewer.getControl().setBackground(
                    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay()
                            .getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY));

        }
    });
    viewer.getControl().addListener(SWT.MouseExit, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            viewer.getControl().setBackground(
                    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay()
                            .getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));

        }
    });

}
```

I want to save the selection even i mouse hover out if that view is already had selected.

Comment: What do you mean _"highlight respective views"_? Highlight how?

Comment: how the user will come to know that which view is active at a time? suppose in four views i have clicked on one view, i want to show it as selected one and remaining are idle. hope u getting me.

Comment: Isn't the "active" view automatically highlighted by Eclipse?

Comment: Yeah.. like that only i too want to show the selected view as active one. I mean In eclipse on click we come to know which view we have selected whether its package explorer view or outline view or some other view,, Like that i too want to do in my application which have these views (1)project explorer view,(2)Page view explorer (3)server view explorer (4) device library views (5) property view .....

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse PartService keeps track of which part (Editors, Views etc...) is currently active. You can add a listener to the service via the PlatfomUI class:

```
IPartListener partListener = ...;
IPartService partService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getPartService();
partService.addPartListener(listener);
```

The IPartListener interface has `partActivated` and `partDeactivated` methods where you can do your highlighting.

Comment: Can we change view title color when it will be active?